# wordpress 404 not found after rewrtie the author link

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, author, 404-error

I want to change the default WordPress author link (which is /author/user_nicename) to/author/user_id.

And I found it's easy to do that, I achieved this in two ways:

1.I just copy the `get_author_posts_url()` function from `wp-includes/author-template.php` and rewrite it in my theme:

```
function ji_get_user_url($author_id, $author_nicename = '') {
global $wp_rewrite;
$auth_ID = (int) $author_id;
$link = $wp_rewrite->get_author_permastruct();
if ( empty($link) ) {
    $file = home_url( '/' );
    $link = $file . '?author=' . $auth_ID;
}else {
    if ( '' == $author_nicename ) {
        $user = get_userdata($author_id);
        if ( !empty($user->user_nicename) )
            $author_nicename = $author_id;
    }
    $link = str_replace('%author%', $author_id, $link);
    $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $link ) );
}
$link = apply_filters( 'author_link', $link, $author_id, $author_nicename );
return $link;
}
```

2.I used the filter:

```
function chang_author_link($link,$author_id,$author_nicename){
$user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
$user_id= $user_info->ID;
$link = str_replace($author_nicename, $user_id, $link);
return $link;
}
add_filter('author_link', 'chang_author_link',10,3);
```

Either way above can successfully change the default author link to /author/user_id, but that they all returned a 404 not found page!

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the puzzle myself.

The truth is ,it's really hard to alter the author link directly by replacing the author slug with an author id.Just like @cjbj said:

> you have moved a sign directing you to Buckingham Palace and expect that by doing so you also have relocated the palace.

We need to approach this issue in other ways.

By default wordpress use /user_nicename/as the slug right? So Let's keep the way it is but altering the "content" of user_nicename.In other words,we make the user_id be the user_nicename.

So just do one thing when there is a new user coming in :

```
wp_update_user(array('user_nicename' => $user_id))
```

All done!

Answer (score 1):

The function [`get_author_posts_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/) retrieves the url where the posts of a certain author are to be found. If you change the url, that doesn't mean the posts are moved.

In other words, you have moved a sign directing you to Buckingham Palace and expect that by doing so you also have relocated the palace. In effect, as you found out, you end up in the middle of nowhere.

Also beware that since you are modifying the existing filter [`author_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/author_link), the modification will also apply to calls originating in other functions. If you want to apply a filter to a custom made function, it is better to define a custom named filter as well.

Comment: so I've worked it out myself.